# Weird session behaviour in codeigniter

Tags: php, session, codeigniter

Following code works fine ..

```
$somearray = getData();

$data = array(
    'user_display_name' => $userdisplayname,
    'username'  => $usernamefromdb,
    'logged_in'  => TRUE,
);
$this->session->set_userdata($data); // used to create user session
```

This works fine with codeigniter and sqlite..

But when i code

```
$data = array(
    'user_display_name' => $userdisplayname,
    'username'  => $usernamefromdb,
    'logged_in'  => TRUE,
    'arrdata' => $somearray
);

$this->session->set_userdata($data); // used to create user session
```

It says session terminated... What can be the issue?

When i do `var_dump($somearray)` it shows the info. Is there any memory limit for sessions??

Thanks

Comment: What is the content of `$somearray`?

Comment: And what version of codeigniter are a you using?

Comment: Cookies can only hold 4KB of data [Session Class CI](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html)

Comment: @JoseAdrian Thankfully, the session is not stored in a cookie. Only the session id is stored there, the session is only stored on the server.

Comment: @Pelle: From Jose's link: "A useful aspect of the session array is that you can add your own data to it and it will be stored in the user's cookie."  The data in CodeIgniter's session is not stored server side, like you would expect with most session implementations.

Comment: @Jose: I'd suggest taking that comment and making it into an answer.

Comment: Thanks but Roopa wants to know why when he executes his code says: session terminated.

Comment: I missed the link. Teaching the wrong makes you learn the right in this place.

Answer (score 4):

I noticed the same issue in one of my applications too. Debugging the problem lead me to discover that CodeIgniter is (was) not properly implementing serialization/unserialization of multi-dimensional arrays. There was actually a bug submitted for that, and I believe they either fixed it or about to fix it. Take a look at the their session lib in Core.

```
function _serialize($data)
{
    if (is_array($data))
    {
        foreach ($data as $key => $val)
        {
            if (is_string($val))
            {
                $data[$key] = str_replace('\\', '{{slash}}', $val);
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (is_string($data))
        {
            $data = str_replace('\\', '{{slash}}', $data);
        }
    }

    return serialize($data);
}
```

Notice that it only goes through 1 level of your array and that the ONLY level that gets the slashes replaced. The problem is that you have multi-dimensional array and there's probably data there that's throwing off serialization and wiping your session.  We fixed it by extending their session library and creating these calls:

```
class MY_Session extends CI_Session {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function _serialize($data)
    {
        $data = $this->_serialize_backslash_recursive($data);

        return serialize($data);
    }

    function _unserialize($data)
    {
        $data = @unserialize(strip_slashes($data));

        return $this->_unserialize_backslash_recursive($data);
    }

    function _serialize_backslash_recursive($data)
    {

        if (is_array($data))
        {
            return array_map(array($this,'_serialize_backslash_recursive'), $data);
        }
        else
        {
            if (is_string($data))
            {
                return str_replace('\\', '{{slash}}', $data);
            }
        }

        return $data;

    }

    function _unserialize_backslash_recursive($data)
    {

        if (is_array($data))
        {
            return array_map(array($this,'_unserialize_backslash_recursive'), $data);
        }
        else
        {
            if (is_string($data))
            {
                return str_replace('{{slash}}', '\\', $data);
            }
        }

        return $data;

    }

}
```

This will now go through all the levels properly. Give it a try and see if it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Codeigniter does not store all the session data in the Database natively (unlike what its makes you believe). It stores the data in the cookie which is limited to 4KB as pointed out by Jose Adrian.

To store all your session data in the DB, use this replacement session class: http://codeigniter.com/wiki/OB_Session/

Storing session data in the database will also be more secure than storing it in a cookie.