# Why would @ operator not suppress E_NOTICE in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, error-handling, deserialization, codeigniter-2

I know better than to ignore errors, I promise. A run of the XML-Sitemaps generator hits URLs without valid session information to please CodeIgniter. The result is one E_NOTICE for every page crawled and a log (and email notifications) that make me bonkers. Nothing breaks and no people or robots are harmed – only my sanity is affected.

Several folks have engineered fixes for the CodeIgniter unserialize() fail:

- Encryption Problem: http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/91456/#758252
- Recursive Serialization Problem: [Weird session behaviour in codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7103608/weird-session-behaviour-in-codeigniter)

I've run with each premise and still get hundreds of the following notices:

```
NOTICE: unserialize() [<a href='function.unserialize'>function.unserialize</a>]: Error at offset 98 of 128 bytes
```

This brings me back to square one with a very simple question. Here's the problematic line 724 of CI's Session.php:

```
$data = @unserialize(strip_slashes($data));
```

I didn't add the suppressive '@' – it was already there. Doesn't that mean that it will specifically suppress E_NOTICE messages if thrown? If not, how could that line possibly generate all these notices that make me want to rip all my hair out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Setting a custom error handler bypasses PHP's error handling — and apparently PHP's error suppression:

> It is important to remember that the standard PHP error handler is completely bypassed for the error types specified by error_types unless the callback function returns FALSE. error_reporting() settings will have no effect and your error handler will be called regardless - however you are still able to read the current value of error_reporting and act appropriately. Of particular note is that this value will be 0 if the statement that caused the error was prepended by the @ error-control operator.

```
<?php
set_error_handler(function ($errno, $errstr) {
    echo $errstr;
}, E_ALL);
@unserialize("foo"); // Still shows $errstr!
```

This will take over for PHP, and probably ignore your error suppression settings. Chances are that CodeIgniter is using its own error handler (which I believe it has) and spitting out errors regardless of the error suppression level.

However, PHP seems to imply that checking the error reporting level and seeing if it's equal to zero will tell you whether or not the error was supposed to be suppressed. So, in theory, you could edit the CodeIgniter error handler and add an `if (error_reporting()) { /* show error */ }`.

Comment: What a glorious day! Thank you for making this so clear – I was finally able to update my exception handler in less than five minutes and I'm greatly relieved as well as better educated. Cheers.